# C++ Windows does window force the waking-up of thread in wait?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-studio, condition-variable

I know that sometime, thread in condition-variable wait can be wake - up from Windows, which send them a notify without reason. So we overload the function wait with a function which verify if the thread must be wake up or not.

Suppose to have this pseudo:

```
if (A == false)
conditionVariable.wait (lock, []() { return (A == true) });
cout << "Exit from wait " << endl;
```

Suppose that immediately before the wait, another thread put A = true, and it does a conditionVariable.notifyAll() (but I cannot listen it because I'm not on wait yet). After that, I enter in the wait and nobody could take the lock in other part of the code. The behaviour of my program is the execution of the cout! I'd like to understand if the motivation is:

A) Even if nobody notify the thread, it exit from the wait because the lock is free and because the condition A==true is true.

B) The synchronization is wrong, teorically your program should be wait forever but a "Windows notify" save you even if you miss the notification.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: at least bring dome dource provign that windows "wake up" waiting threads randomly.

Comment: The lock prevents a race condition. The spurious wakeups would be due to other events like signals.

Comment: This is what the lock is for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the reference mentions that wait-with-predicate is equivalent to:

```
while (!pred()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

Your `if` is unnecessary. As to your question: behaviour is still **B)** (broken) for the reasons you list yourself. Note that even the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) has this snippet before notifying the waiting thread:

```
// send data to the worker thread
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
    ready = true;
    std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
}
cv.notify_one();
```

Acquiring the lock first before setting `ready` ensures the worker sees the expected sequence.

Comment: "Your if is unnecessary": I disagree, because A could change between the if and the wait :)

Comment: @JoeMatt note that `if(!A) { while(!A) dostuff(); }` has an unnecessary `if(!A)` in every way shape or form